# .htaccess rule does rewrite URL in address bar

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, post

I have a website where my links look like this
http://www.domain.com/index.php?lang=English&inc=canyoning
I managed to write rewriteRule like this:

`RewriteRule (German|English)\/(.*) http://www.domain.com/index.php?lang=$1&inc=$2 [NC,R]`

Now my  links look like this: `<a href="http://www.domain.com/English/canyoning">`...

This works, but I can see non user friendly URL in browser address bar. How can I tell browser to use link like `/English/canyoning` in URL and not `index.php?lang=English&inc=canyoning`?

And second: I would like to use forms on page.
There is no difference, whether I use form method =GET or POST, No variables come to destination site.

I guess there is my rewriteRule wrong. How to fix those issues?

Thank you for help!

Comment: You should ask your second question separately. The FAQ format of StackOverflow doesn't work well with multiple questions.

Comment: Also, you might get a better response over at http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you are doing a redirect not a rewrite.. (The `R` flag indicates a [Redirect](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r))

So remove the R flag should fix your issue.

You may also need to remove the hardcoded domain. As you are doing a rewrite you cant rewrite to a different domain.

ie. Change

```
RewriteRule (German|English)\/(.*) http://www.domain.com/index.php?lang=$1&inc=$2 [NC,R]
```

To

```
RewriteRule (German|English)\/(.*) /index.php?lang=$1&inc=$2 [NC]
```